# Event detection in multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

I've have the following multivariate one second time series composed of that I can manually label and its based on sudden value changes (increase)from zone 1 to zone 2 and (decrease) from zone 2 to 3.

I do have several datasets of this same process and I'm wondering if I can develop a machine learning model to identify these zones for new time series of the same process. I don't have anything labeled so initially so it'll have to be an unsupervised or clustering models but I can label some of these processes for training. I've also thought on feature engineering for these time series as well.

I'm really just in the initial stages so any input or ideas would be really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Can you guarantee the transition is clearly defined around 10k psi? If so, you could implement some kind of flutter filter, and then just threshold a trigger to tell you when you transition.

Comment: The transition at that specific point isn't guaranteed (it will change from process to process) but the shape of the process is basically the same. I'm not really familiar with a flutter filter,  where can I can find more information about it.

Comment: It's not a technical term that I'm aware of; it just means you don't want a single noisy data point that's abnormally high to be a transition. A percentile filter would work just fine for smoothing out that sort of thing, or about any sort of low-pass filter. I wouldn't throw ML at this problem when the signal is so rich in features you can detect. I would try to use a deterministic algorithm to find these shapes.

Comment: I've tried low pass filters in the past but I've found a lot of false positives and several deterministic/analytical methods and little success. I'd like to try some ML methods to compare with what a I currently have and have a better perspective.